# How to calculate column sum for models with many-to-one relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a small issue and I kinda got stuck myself. Maybe you could help me with a suggestion in order to achieve the following scenario.

**Requirement:** I am trying to work at a food journal application. What I want is to display on the home page all the jurnals along with the total of the record's calories added to a specific jurnal.

My homepage posts look like this:

[Posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFuYx.png)

**My models**

```
class Journal(models.Model):
    date_juornal = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    note = models.TextField(default="", blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Record(models.Model):
    journal = models.ForeignKey(Journal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    food = models.ForeignKey(FoodType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qty = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class FoodType(models.Model):
    food = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    calories = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**My View***

```
class HomeView(ListView):

def get(self, request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        journals = Juornal.objects.filter(
            user=request.user).order_by('-date_juornal')
       rec1 = Record.objects.annotate(kcal=F('foodtype__calories'))
       rec2 = rec1.annotate(total=(F('kcal') * F('cantitate')) / 100)
        context = {
            'journals': journals,
            'records': records
        }
        return render(request, 'nutriapp/home.html', context)
    else:
        return redirect('login')
```

Comment: what kind of problem are you facing?

Comment: I am looking to calculate the following: Record.qty * FoodType.calories / 100. Then to make a total of this rows at the Jurnal level. And least this info to be displayed on home page for each journal.